# javascript ok/cancel dialog box appear once per session

Tags: javascript, alert

I am trying to get this to work in my iweb page hosted not on MobileMe. With the code below I continue to get the alert box on each refresh of the page instead of once per session. I am a total newbie here so be kind please.

```
//Alert message once script- By JavaScript Kit
//Credit notice must stay intact for use
//Visit http://javascriptkit.com for this script

//specify message to alert
var answer=confirm("Click OK if you have been cleared Sutter's HR department to start       
volunteering.")
if (answer)
 alert ("Excellent!!  Please select your dates directly within the scheduling calendar.")
else
 alert ("Let's get to it then. Contact Ruth in HR at 576-4208 to schedule an appointment     so you can get started.")


///No editing required beyond here/////

//answer only once per browser session (0=no, 1=yes)
var once_per_session=1


function get_cookie(Name) {
  var search = Name + "="
  var returnvalue = "";
  if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
    offset = document.cookie.indexOf(search)
    if (offset != -1) { // if cookie exists
      offset += search.length
      // set index of beginning of value
      end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", offset);
      // set index of end of cookie value
      if (end == -1)
         end = document.cookie.length;
      returnvalue=unescape(document.cookie.substring(offset, end))
      }
   }
  return returnvalue;
}

function alertornot(){
if (get_cookie('alerted')==''){
loadalert()
document.cookie="alerted=yes"
}
}

function loadalert(){
alert(alertmessage)
}

if (once_per_session==0)
loadalert()
else
alertornot()

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code calls this once per session:

```
alert(alertmessage)
```

but the code on top is called on each load of the script.

Moreover - I don't see where `alertmessage` is defined... 
So You probably want to put the code from the top inside the `loadalert` function resulting in this:

```
function loadalert(){
var answer=confirm("Click OK if you have been cleared Sutter's HR department to start  volunteering.")
if (answer)
 alert ("Excellent!!  Please select your dates directly within the scheduling calendar.")
else
 alert ("Let's get to it then. Contact Ruth in HR at 576-4208 to schedule an appointment     so you can get started.")

}
```

EDIT:

And BTW - start using curly braces. It helps in debug and in understanding where You are. :)